# How do I scale a matrix that's already made?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, matrices

I just made a 15x15 matrix in the environment

```
\begin{pmatrix} 
%12 entries row by column go here
\end{pmatrix}
```

I just found out I cannot compile this.

Comment: `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}` -- by default `amsmath` sets the value of the `MaxMatrixCols` counter to `10`, I think `mathtools` does not change the value as well (untested)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, found it but my matrix still went way overboard.

Comment: If your matrix is too wide, you should consider using smaller fonts, reorganising it (showing only portions of it) or using `mathtools`'s `psmallmatrix` environment instead, perhaps

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is answered in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}` (or any other appropiate value) -- by default, the counter value is set to `10`.

The counter value can be changed at any time, having no effect on matrices typeset earlier in the document (as the counter value is globally set with `\setcounter` (unless one knows the trick ;-))

In case of the matrix being too wide, choose a smaller font size, reorganize the matrix or use `psmallmatrix` (or any of the provided `...smallmatrix` environments given by `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}

\begin{document}

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 
\end{pmatrix}
$

$
\begin{psmallmatrix} 
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 
\end{psmallmatrix}
$


\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20
\end{pmatrix}
$

$
\begin{psmallmatrix} 
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20
\end{psmallmatrix}
$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Behold the very sophisticated matrix entries ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to make this *even* smaller?

Comment: @jacobsmith: Well, using `\tiny` as font size declaration, perhaps... But you asked about the numbers of columns that did not work, not about the overshooting of your matrix. That's a totally different question ...

Comment: you mean inside the entries?

Comment: @jacobsmith: No, you can't change font size in math mode. You must set it before, best with `{\tiny$\begin{psmallmatrix}...\end{psmallmatrix}$}`. Note the outer `{...}` pair! Please be aware that you must include a magnifying glass already for such a small font if you purpose to use this font size in a printed copy.